# How to maintain the previously selected language (I used php arrays and ?lang=) after clicking a link?

Tags: php, arrays, lang

I have the following code:

```
  <html>
        <head>
            <title><?php echo $GLOBALS['L']['title']; ?></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <ul id="language-selection">
                <li><a href="index.php?lang=english">English</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php?lang=french">French</a></li>
            </ul>
            <h1><?php echo $GLOBALS['L']['h1']; ?></h1>
            <p><?php echo $GLOBALS['L']['p1']; ?></p>
            <ul id="language-selection">
                <li><a href="about.php">About Page</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Page</a></li>
            </ul>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**set_locale.php:**

```
<?php
/*
 * File: set_locale.php
 */

// Get the language from the query string, or set a default.
($language = @$_GET['lang']) or $language = 'english';

// Set up a list of possible values, and make sure the
// selected language is valid.
$allowed_locales = array('english', 'french');
if(!in_array($language, $allowed_locales)) 
    $language = 'english'; // Set default if it is invalid.


// Inlclude the selected language
include "locale/$language.php";

// Make it global, so it is accessible everywhere in the code.
$GLOBALS['L'] = $locale;
?>
```

It works OK, but if I click the `about.php` and `contact.php` link.
The page returns to the default language: English.
What can I do so that when I click `about.php` or `contact.php` ends up like this:

```
about.php?lang=english
contact.php?lang=french
```

respectively, in other words I want the URL to remember the `?lang=` ending.
What's the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to append it to every outgoing link:

```
 <li><a href="about.php<?php echo "?lang=".$GLOBALS['L']; ?>">About Page</a></li>
```

a nice way of dealing with multi-language sites in general is, if your server supports it, `mod_rewrite` to rewrite "virtual" URLs like

```
www.example.com/en/about.php
```

and map them internally to

```
www.example.com/about.php?lang=en
```

there's a beginner's guide on that [**here**](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite) and official documentation [**here**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html).

I'm no mod_rewrite guru but this works for me:

```
 RewriteEngine on
 Options +FollowSymlinks

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z][a-z])(/.*)?$      
 RewriteRule (.*) %2?lang=%1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

it maps

- `www.domain.com/en/about.php` to `/about.php?lang=en`
- `www.domain.com/fr/about.php` to `/about.php?lang=fr`
- `www.domain.com/es/` to `/?lang=es` = usually index.php

It maps any occurrence of a two-letter, lowercase `www.example.com/xy`, so you shouldn't have any directories with two letters on your root level to work with this.

Comment: +1 Yes, my server have it enabled. Thanks, but how do I apply the tutorial to my example?

Comment: I tried the first example and the URL ended up like this: http://localhost/...contact.php?lang=Array
What happened?

Comment: @jano hang on, I'll write an example.

Comment: +1 Always keep your language in the URL. You can use an automatic redirect from `/` to choose a default language based on the `Accept-Language` header or account settings, but after that there should generally be a different URL for each language version of a page, so that users can navigate between languages as necessary, and search engines can index each language.

Comment: You don't even have to use rewriting to achieve this; you can use a simple `Alias` to point each language to the same set of PHP files, and then have the script sniff `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` to choose which language to display.

Comment: @bobince good point, but I have often had trouble using `Alias` on shared hosting in the past, while rewrite worked like a charm. Anyway, care to write down an `Alias` example for completeness? @jano I added a working mod_rewrite example.

Comment: Thanks Pekka I'll try it out. DO I have to create a .htaccess file and upload it to the root of my server?

Comment: @jano what happens when you enter `domain.com/en/about.php`?

Comment: @jano there is only one file in play. mod_rewrite creates *virtual* URLs that are mapped to your php files. There is no need to change anything in your files except take into account that the browser thinks you are in a directory (`/en/`) while really you are not.

Comment: this is the file tree of my files:

D:\wamp\www\tests\php-multilingual-arrays\locale\en.php
D:\wamp\www\tests\php-multilingual-arrays\locale\fr.php

Does this affect your example?
(I can't enter the /en/about.php because it doesn't exists)

Comment: @jano You need to update the mod_rewrite example to reflect your directory structure (add /tests/php-..... everywhere) or move the whole thing down to the root level.

Comment: I moved everything to my root directory but when I click about.php, it still coming back to English (contact.php?lang=Array so it calls the default). Never mind I used the Session and Cookie technique and arrays from a previous question of mine (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298372/my-multilingual-website-with-only-basic-php-without-zend-translate-gettext-etc) and it seems to works. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @jano when you call `/fr/about.php`, all links inside it (the ?lang= part is not necessary in that case) will automatically point to the french version. That's the beauty of it - the browser is tricked into thinking it's in the /fr directory while in reality, all calls go to just one `about.php`. This works, and is definitely better than sessions - worth trying again.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to learn about storing information in sessions.

http://learnitscreencasts.net/2009/07/18/beginners/beginners-guide-php-sessions/

Comment: Sessions won't work because I could well have a tab open with the english, and another with the french version.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) and store the persistent options there. It has the advantage of allowing people to copy links to others without forcing their settings upon them, if you so desire such.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`output_add_rewrite_var`](http://php.net/output_add_rewrite_var) to add that argument to the URLs. Just call the following before you output your contents:

```
output_add_rewrite_var('lang', $language);
```